# Why animation with canvas / scss is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, sass

I'd like to create a rain of pretzels, I have taken the code from codepen.io and when I execute it over there it works. [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/ruigewaard/pen/Podmea) but when I execute it locally it is not working. Could someone help me?

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page TEST</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
    <script src='../main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>    
    
<script src='../main.js'></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #061928;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    
    if(canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var w = canvas.width;
      var h = canvas.height;
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = "https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/138154/isolated/preview/5d645814754f5509238ef242137b0fa3-oktoberfest-pretzel-cookie-illustration-by-vexels.png"; 
      
      var init = [];
      var maxParts = 1000;
      for(var a = 0; a < maxParts; a++) {
        init.push({
          x: Math.random() * w,
          y: Math.random() * h,
          l: Math.random() * 30,
          xs: -4 + Math.random() * 4 + 2,
          ys: Math.random() * 10 + 10
        })
      }
      
      var particles = [];
      for(var b = 0; b < maxParts; b++) {
        particles[b] = init[b];
      }
      
      function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        for(var c = 0; c < particles.length; c++) {
          var p = particles[c];
          ctx.drawImage(img, p.x, p.y, p.l, p.l); // draw image at particle's position
        }
        move();
      }
      
      function move() {
        for(var b = 0; b < particles.length; b++) {
          var p = particles[b];
          p.x += p.xs;
          p.y += p.ys;
          if(p.x > w || p.y > h) {
            p.x = Math.random() * w;
            p.y = -20;
          }
        }
      }
      
      setInterval(draw, 30);
      
    }
  });
```

SCSS

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #061928;
  }
```

style.css.map

```
{"version":3,"sources":["style.scss","style.css"],"names":[],"mappings":";AACA;EACI,SAAA;EACA,gBAAA;EACA,mBAAA;ACCJ","file":"style.css"}
```

I install several times SASS, I empty my caches, and adapt my code several times but it does not work.

Comment: What debugging have you done? For example, have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see if there are any errors on the console or in the CSS, and are all the files being loaded OK?

Comment: I have checked the console but everything seems to be alright. And I have ran the same code on codepen and it works just fine over there

Comment: I found thz solution, was something really stupid, I forgot to add:
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="path/to/your/custom/script.js"></script>

Must be because I'm tired, that I couldn't find the solution, thank you anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Most likely its due to not having jquery imported into your website
add

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`

To the html above the main js

It will look like so.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page TEST</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src='../main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>    
    <script src='../main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main thing here which is actually far more important than making it work, is how you would be able to solve this yourself in the future. Chrome and other web browsers typically have dev tools which will make solving issues like these much easier. To open dev tools in Chrome press f12

Comment: Thank you very much Popeye, yes I realized that after posting the question. And yes I'm trying to improve myself in the aspect of solving problems in my codes, that's why I also post here when I have a question, in order to learn from people who are experts on the subject, like you. Thank you very much again